# Insert for each value in a table that matches criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've got a few tables. The end goal is to insert n records into t3 as what exists in t1, as long as t1.id matches t2.id.  How about I go about doing that?

You can assume the most basic schema in this case.

T1 would have the following records

```
number|line
1, 1
1, 3
1, 5
```

T2 would have the following record

```
number
1
```

The records inserted should be

```
number|line|0|0
1,1,0,0
1,3,0,0
1,5,0,0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for an inner join on `number`.

```
INSERT INTO t3
            (number,
             line,
             x,
             y)
SELECT t1.number,
       t1.line,
       0,
       0
       FROM t1
            INNER JOIN t2
                       ON t2.number = t1.number;
```

Comment: That got me close enough to what I needed.  Thanks.